# Missing Page/Item Counts

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, telerik, radgrid

*I posted this on the [Telerik Forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/missing-page-item-counts.aspx) but I've got a feeling I'll get a faster reply here, apologies if the cross-posting is frowned upon.*

My RadGrid's used to display Page and Item counts in the bottom right of each Grid.  I recently upgraded Telerik from v2011.3.1305 to v2012.1.411.

Typical markup for one of my grids:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="AssetGrid" runat="server" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowPaging="True"
    AllowSorting="True" GridLines="None" GroupingSettings-CaseSensitive="false" Skin="Web20"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPageIndexChanged="AssetGrid_PageIndexChanged" OnItemCreated="AssetGrid_ItemCreated"
    OnItemDataBound="AssetGrid_ItemDataBound"
    OnPreRender="AssetGrid_PreRender" OnSortCommand="AssetGrid_SortCommand" OnNeedDataSource="AssetGrid_NeedDataSource"
    EnableLinqExpressions="false">
    <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true">
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
        <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowAssetSelected" />
    </ClientSettings>
    <MasterTableView EditMode="InPlace" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" ShowFooter="false"
        EnableColumnsViewState="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellSpacing="-1" DataKeyNames="AsId"
        Font-Size="90%" AllowCustomSorting="true" AllowCustomPaging="true" Width="100%">
        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" Visible="true" AlwaysVisible="true" />
        <!-- RowIndicatorColumn, ExpandCollapseColumn, Columns, etc -->
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

I've only included below the code for NeedDataSource, but if any of the others help, let me know and I'll get them posted:

```
protected void AssetGrid_NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    var collection = getAssets();
    AssetGrid.VirtualItemCount = collection.Count;
    AssetGrid.DataSource = collection.Skip(AssetGrid.PageSize * 
        AssetGrid.CurrentPageIndex).Take(AssetGrid.PageSize);
}
```

The grids however, are displaying the pager row like this:

[image: Pager Display]

Is there a setting I've missed to enable the page/item counts in the bottom right as shown in pretty much all of the [Telerik Pager Examples](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-pageritem.html)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add `PageSize="10"` to markup and see if it works?

Comment: @rs - I added the page size attribute to the MasterTableView, unfortunately it doesn't appear to have made any difference.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

try use this code for your PagerStyle:

```
    <PagerStyle PagerTextFormat="Page: {4} &amp;nbsp;Count: {5}" 
                Font-Names="Arial"
                ForeColor="#bebebe"
                Font-Size="12px"
                Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric"
                PageSizeLabelText="your lable for page size"
                AlwaysVisible="true"/>
```

also you can try these propertis:

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ... 
                    OnItemCreated="RadGrid_ItemCreated"                                        
                    PagerStyle-ShowPagerText="true">
```

and Your delegate method for the ItemCreated event should look like this:

```
protected void RadGrid_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridPagerItem)
    {
        var dropDown = (RadComboBox)e.Item.FindControl("PageSizeComboBox");
        var totalCount = ((GridPagerItem)e.Item).Paging.DataSourceCount;
        var sizes = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            {"10", "10"},
            {"20", "20"},
            {"50", "50"}
        };
        if (totalCount > 100)
        {
            sizes.Add("100", "100");
        }
        if (totalCount > 200)
        {
            sizes.Add("200", "200");
        }
        sizes.Add("All", totalCount.ToString());

        dropDown.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var size in sizes)
        {
            var cboItem = new RadComboBoxItem() { Text = size.Key, Value = size.Value };
            cboItem.Attributes.Add("ownerTableViewId", e.Item.OwnerTableView.ClientID);
            dropDown.Items.Add(cboItem);
        }
        dropDown.FindItemByValue(e.Item.OwnerTableView.PageSize.ToString()).Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: hah, the question is 4 years old. It's been about that long since I last had to deal with WebForms, let alone telerik. Thanks though.

Comment: hah, Unfortunately my company that i have job right now , we are working by webforms and telerik. our HIS project in very huge that migrate to MVC , ...